# Irreducibility of twisted cubic curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, curves

I want to prove the following proposition to show the irreducibility of the twisted cubic curve. What would be the best way to prove it?

We define a homogeneous ideal $I$ in the polynomial ring ${\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]}$ as follows: $$I=(xz-y^2,xw-yz,yw-z^2).$$ Additionally, we define a homomorphism $\phi$ from ${\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]}$ to ${\mathbb{C}[s,t]}$ as follows: $$\phi(f(x,y,zw))=f(s^3,s^2t,st^2,t^3).$$ Then ${\operatorname{Ker}\phi=I}$.

Comment: Maybe Cox, Little and O'Shea Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms Proposition 6 in chapter 4 section 5 Any variety defined by a rational parametrization is irreducible.

Comment: I just realized that my answer wasn't relevant to your actual question (which is showing that $I = \operatorname{ker} \phi$). I apologize for that.